# Combine update statement and select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer and I'm trying combine an update and a select statment into one. I know that Oracle dosen't support FROM or JOINS directly in the update statement and I therefor put the select in a subquery but it still don't work.

I have got two tables; MASTERTABLE and TESTTABLE.

MASTERTABLE contain an ID_NUMBER column and a  TESTTABLE_ID column.

TESTTABLE contains a TESTTABLE_ID column and a TEST_COLUMN column.

What I want to do is to update the TEST_COLUMN value while only knowing the ID_NUMBER.

What my statement looks like:

```
UPDATE TESTTABLE
SET TEST_COLUMN= 'Testvalue'
WHERE TESTTABLE.TESTTABLE_ID IN (SELECT MASTERTABLE.TESTTABLE_ID
FROM MASTERTABLE
WHERE ID_NUMBER=11);
```

But I get stuck in some kind of loop. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: What makes you think that you're "stuck in some kind of loop"? Is the query just never finishing? Are you receiving an error message? How large are your tables?

Comment: I try to run the the query in Oracle SQL Developers Worksheet script runner and it just continues for ever, it seams like the query doesn't finish. I'm using a couple of small trial tables with only 3 rows each.

Comment: With tables that small it should indeed be returning almost immediately. Hopefully one of the Oracle specialists can point you to the solution here, as the query itself looks fine to me. Is it possible that you have another thread running that has a lock on the table and is preventing the update? This might help you track that down: http://www.oraclerecipes.com/monitoring/find-blocking-sessions/

Comment: I have no problem running a simple update query on the MASTERTABLE so at least that part shouldn't be blocked.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem. The solution is usage of `MERGE` operation instead of `UPDATE`.

```
        MERGE INTO TESTTABLE t
        USING 
        (
          SELECT m.ID_NUMBER num,
                 m.TESTTABLE_ID id
          FROM MASTERTABLE m
        ) newnum ON (t.TESTTABLE_ID = newnum.id)
        WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
        SET t.TEST_COLUMN = newnum.num;
```

Comment: Although this is a viable work around (and one I "overuse" myself too much :) - I just find MERGE so much easier to read ) .. I wouldn't exactly call it the "solution".  His UPDATE appears to be perfectly fine - so something else is likely causing his "issue" ;)

Comment: This solution still leaves the ScriptRunner running indefinitely. No error message the query just never finishes :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try any one of this in Oracle

**Normal Update**

```
UPDATE
      TESTTABLE
SET
      TEST_COLUMN= 'Testvalue'
WHERE
      EXISTS
          (SELECT MASTERTABLE.TESTTABLE_ID 
           FROM MASTERTABLE 
           WHERE ID_NUMBER=11);
```

**Using Inline View (If it is considered updateable by Oracle)**

**Note**: If you face a non key preserved row error add an index to resolve the same to make it update-able

```
UPDATE
      (SELECT
            TESTTABLE.TEST_COLUMN AS OLD,
            'Testvalue' AS NEW
       FROM
                TESTTABLE
            INNER JOIN
                MASTERTABLE
            ON TESTTABLE.TESTTABLE_ID = MASTERTABLE.TESTTABLE_ID
       WHERE ID_NUMBER=11) T
SET
      T.OLD     = T.NEW;
```

**Using Merge**

```
MERGE INTO
      TESTTABLE
USING
      (SELECT
            T1.ROWID AS RID,
            T2.TESTTABLE_ID
       FROM
                TESTTABLE T1
            INNER JOIN
                MASTERTABLE T2
            ON TESTTABLE.TESTTABLE_ID = MASTERTABLE.TESTTABLE_ID
       WHERE ID_NUMBER=11)
ON
      ( ROWID = RID )
WHEN MATCHED
THEN
    UPDATE SET TEST_COLUMN= 'Testvalue';
```

Comment: Solution #1 and #2 shows the same problems as the my original attempt at a solution. The third one throws an error: SQL Error: ORA-00904: "ASSERTION"."VOCABULARY_ID": invalid identifier

Comment: Where does this assertion.vocabulary_id come from?

Comment: gah, supposed to be SQL Error: ORA-00904: "MASTERTABLE"."TESTTABLE_ID": invalid identifier

Comment: you mentioned "MASTERTABLE contain an ID_NUMBER column and a TESTTABLE_ID column." which means there is  such table and column??

Comment: Yes there is such a table and column but it still returns a invalid identifer error on solution #3

Answer (score 0):

The problem was as Tom H wrote a blocking problem. When I started working on the project today all of the solutions worked.